# Product Price Break SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,

```
PRODTBL consists of
   Product Name
   Quantity

PRICETBL consists of 
    Product Name
    Min Qty
    Max Qty
    Price
```

I need to find the correct price based on the Product Name and Quantity within the Min Qty and Max Qty.

Samples:

```
PRODTBL
Product Name  Quantity
Product1      16
Product2      100
Product1      4
Product3      7

PRICETBL
Product Name  Min Qty  Max Qty  Price
Product1      0        5        1.99
Product1      6        10       1.59
Product1      11       999      1.09
Product2      0        10       10.00
Product2      11       100      5.00
Product2      101      9999     2.50
Product3      0        100      1.00
Product3      101      10000    0.50
Product3      10001    99999    0.25
```

From the sample data above I want to output:

```
Product1      16    1.09
Product2      100   5.00
Product1      4     1.99
Product3      7     1.00
```

Comment: So what are you asking? What have *you* tried to solve the problem yourself? Why didn't it work? Please don't treat [so] like a free coding service, it isn't one; it's a Q&A website.

Comment: Did you try to join the tables?

Comment: Seems like what you should be looking into is `JOIN` syntax; a fundamental part of the language. You probably need to look at some tutorials to help you get started on the language.

Comment: Larnu, thanks so much for you assistance and support, I'll remember to block you in future so as to not waste my time!

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like

```
 SELECT PR.ProductName,PR.Quantity
 FROM PRODTBL AS PR
 JOIN PRICETBL AS PRICE ON PR.ProductName=PRICE.ProductName 
    AND PR.Quantity>=PRICE.MinQty AND PR.Quantity<=PRICE.MaxQty
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much for this...complete mind fog when trying to solve it!!!